# Why can't this code successfully parse the date string?

Tags: macros, expl3, date

As an attempt to practice with expl3, I am trying to parse numerical date string to French. There is a `\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n` which receives a string of form `yyyy-mm-dd` (or `yyyy-mm` or `mm-dd`, which is not done yet), and tries to convert it to French text. However, it cannot successfully parse the `yyyy-mm-dd` string and pass the three integers to `\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn`.

Here is what I've tried so far. Where does it go wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__mymodule_year_int
\int_new:N \l__mymodule_month_int
\int_new:N \l__mymodule_day_int

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_text_superscript:n { \textsuperscript { #1 } }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
      {
        \__mymodule_parse_yyyymmdd:www #1 \q_stop
        \exp_args:Nx \cs_if_exist_use:cTF { mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_ \languagename :nnn }
          {
            { \l__mymodule_year_int }
            { \l__mymodule_month_int }
            { \l__mymodule_day_int }
          }
          { #1 }
      }
      {
        \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
          {
            %%
          }
          {
            \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
              {
                %%
              }
              { ?? }
          }
      }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__mymodule_parse_yyyymmdd:www #1-#2-#3 \q_stop
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_year_int  { #1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_month_int { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_day_int   { #3 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_month_day_french:nn { #2 } { #3 }
    \c_space_tl
    #1
  }

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_french:nn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n { #2 }
    \c_space_tl
    #1
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_month_day_french:nn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n { #2 }
    \c_space_tl
    \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
      { 1 }  { janvier   }
      { 2 }  { février   }
      { 3 }  { mars      }
      { 4 }  { avril     }
      { 5 }  { mai       }
      { 6 }  { juin      }
      { 7 }  { juillet   }
      { 8 }  { août      }
      { 9 }  { septembre }
      { 10 } { octobre   }
      { 11 } { novembre  }
      { 12 } { décembre  }
    } { #1 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { 1 } { 1 \mymodule_text_superscript:n { er } }
      } { #1 }
  }



\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n {2021-06-03}



\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but make sure to use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` when your macros contain other non-expandable macros.  Also, variables (like integers) should start with their scope, so `\l__mymodule_year_int` instead of `\__mymodule_year_int`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik May I ask how can one usually find out if there are non-expandable macros involved?

Comment: If you look at the documentation in `interface3`, macros marked with a ★ or a ☆ are expandable, and everything else is not.  If your macro contains any non-expandable macro, it is also non-expandable.  If you are using some non-expl3 macro, you can find out experimentally by doing `\edef\x{<macro>}\show\x`.  If what shows in the terminal is what you expect, the macro is (likely) expandable.  If it explodes into an error or shows gibberish, it's not expandable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were getting an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   j
```

because your code was doing:

```latex
\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn
  \l__mymodule_year_int \l__mymodule_month_int \l__mymodule_day_int
```

with this definition of `\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn`:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_month_day_french:nn { #2 } { #3 }
    \c_space_tl
    #1
  }
```

This would just “use” `#1`, which is `\l__mymodule_year_int`, which is equivalent to just typing:

```latex
using an \l__mymodule_year_int causes an error
```

You cannot use an integer variable by just writing it out.  You must precede it with `\int_use:N`.  So one solution would be to write `\int_use:N #1` in that definition (and the one for the day).  A better solution is to use the `V`-type expansion to pass the `V`alue of the integer variables to the macro, so inside the macro you don't have to worry about what type of data you passed to it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__mymodule_year_int
\int_new:N \l__mymodule_month_int
\int_new:N \l__mymodule_day_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_text_superscript:n { \textsuperscript { #1 } }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
      {
        \__mymodule_parse_yyyymmdd:www #1 \s_stop
        \cs_if_exist_use:cTF { mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_ \languagename :VVV }
          {
            \l__mymodule_year_int
            \l__mymodule_month_int
            \l__mymodule_day_int
          }
          { #1 }
      }
      {
        \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
          {
            %%
          }
          {
            \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
              {
                %%
              }
              { ?? }
          }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_parse_yyyymmdd:www #1-#2-#3 \s_stop
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_year_int  { #1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_month_int { #2 }
    \int_set:Nn \l__mymodule_day_int   { #3 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_month_day_french:nn { #2 } { #3 }
    \c_space_tl
    #1
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day_french:nnn { VVV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_french:nn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n { #2 }
    \c_space_tl
    #1
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_month_day_french:nn
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n { #2 }
    \c_space_tl
    \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_month_french:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
      { 1 }  { janvier   }
      { 2 }  { février   }
      { 3 }  { mars      }
      { 4 }  { avril     }
      { 5 }  { mai       }
      { 6 }  { juin      }
      { 7 }  { juillet   }
      { 8 }  { août      }
      { 9 }  { septembre }
      { 10 } { octobre   }
      { 11 } { novembre  }
      { 12 } { décembre  }
    } { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { 1 } { 1 \mymodule_text_superscript:n { er } }
      } { #1 }
  }



\mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n {2021-06-03}



\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Phelype, may I take the opportunity to mention that a conditional/predicate to test whether "something" is an integer is sorely missed.  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133884/discussion-between-gusbrs-and-phelype-oleinik).

Comment: @gusbrs If "integer" denotes something that already forms or expands to a valid TeX-<number>-quantity, then a 100% reliable test seems to be a hard problem: A sequence of tokens may form an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm. Checking if that yields a <number> subsumes checking if an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm terminates at all. (Might be an infinite loop or the like.)  This reminds me of the halting-problem.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I was hoping for something to guard against the sensitivity of integer expressions. But take a look at the discussion in chat, Phelype provided some good insight, and also some interesting links on related discussion upstream.

Comment: @gusbrs I follow the discussion about checking for valid TeX-<number> quantity as defined in the TeXbook for more than 20 years. No one came up with a 100% foolproof solution so far.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Oh, thanks for the pointer! I'll look into it.

Comment: @gusbrs It is in Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode. (The chapter with these nice definitions in terms of Backus-Naur-notation.) The paragraph in question begins with "Let us begin our study of TeX’s syntax by discussing the precise meanings of quantities like <number>, <dimen>, and <glue> that occur frequently as arguments to commands. The most important of these is <number>, which specifies an integer value. Here’s exactly what a <number> is:..." What follows can be seen as an invitation to successively look things up. ;->

Comment: @gusbrs The TeXbook, however, does not cover extensions. E.g., `\numexpr` needs to be looked up in the e-TeX-manual.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you! :)

Comment: @gusbrs Back then looking up things in order to learn what kind of <number>-quantity to use with `\romannumeral`-expansion (a chardef-token denoting 0 terminates `\romannumeral`-expansion completely; an alphabetic constant like `\^^@` triggers `\romannumeral` into expanding things while searching for an <optional space>) was a real pain. The face-palm I gave myself in front of the mirror when I realized that I could have saved myself all that TeXbook searching by just looking at expl3's f-type expansion and at  "controlled expansion" via `\exp:w`...`\exp:end` must have looked funny. ;->

Comment: @UlrichDiez :-)

Answer (score 1):

We should not forget that we have much more simple programming language: low level TeX:

```
\def\monthdef#1 #2 {\expandafter\def\csname m:#1\endcsname{#2}}

\monthdef 1   janvier   
\monthdef 2   février   
\monthdef 3   mars      
\monthdef 4   avril     
\monthdef 5   mai       
\monthdef 6   juin      
\monthdef 7   juillet   
\monthdef 8   août      
\monthdef 9   septembre 
\monthdef 10  octobre   
\monthdef 11  novembre  
\monthdef 12  décembre  

\catcode`\_=11

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\display_date_year_month_day #1{\display_dateA #1;}
\def\display_dateA #1-#2-#3;{\tmpnum=#3\relax \the\tmpnum \
   \tmpnum=#2\relax \csname m:\the\tmpnum\endcsname \
   #1%
}

\display_date_year_month_day {2021-06-03}

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your code. You can check correctness of the input with

```
\regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}(|-\d{1,2}) \Z } { #1 }
```

so the last group might be missing.

After that you can split the input via `\seq_set_split:Nnn` and call a generic date function to which you also pass the current language (expanded).

The next step is to use the localized version. If the day is missing, the third argument will be 0 and you can check for it in the localized function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% for testing
\NewDocumentCommand{\displaydate}{m}
  {
    \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_date_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_text_superscript:n { \textsuperscript { #1 } }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:n
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}(|-\d{1,2}) \Z } { #1 }
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mymodule_date_seq { - } { #1 }
        \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:Veee
          \languagename
          { \seq_item:Nn \l__mymodule_date_seq { 1 } } % year
          { \seq_item:Nn \l__mymodule_date_seq { 2 } } % month
          { \seq_item:Nn \l__mymodule_date_seq { 3 } } % day
      }
      {
       ???#1???
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:nnnn
  {
    \use:c { __mymodule_display_date_#1:nnn } { #2 } { #3 } { \int_eval:n { 0#4 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymodule_display_date_year_month_day:nnnn { Veee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mymodule_display_date_english:nnn
  {
    % month
    \int_case:nn { #2 }
      {
        { 1 }  { January   }
        { 2 }  { February  }
        { 3 }  { March     }
        { 4 }  { April     }
        { 5 }  { May       }
        { 6 }  { June      }
        { 7 }  { July      }
        { 8 }  { August    }
        { 9 }  { September }
        { 10 } { October   }
        { 11 } { November  }
        { 12 } { December  }
      }
    % day
    \int_compare:nF { #3 == 0 } { \nobreakspace #3 }
    % year
    ,\nobreakspace #1
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mymodule_display_date_french:nnn
  {
    % day
    \int_compare:nF { #3 == 0 } { \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n { #3 } \nobreakspace }
    % month
    \int_case:nn { #2 }
      {
        { 1 }  { janvier   }
        { 2 }  { février   }
        { 3 }  { mars      }
        { 4 }  { avril     }
        { 5 }  { mai       }
        { 6 }  { juin      }
        { 7 }  { juillet   }
        { 8 }  { août      }
        { 9 }  { septembre }
        { 10 } { octobre   }
        { 11 } { novembre  }
        { 12 } { décembre  }
      }
    \nobreakspace #1
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_date_day_french:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { 1 } { 1 \mymodule_text_superscript:n { er } }
      }
      { #1 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\displaydate{abdarrr}

\displaydate{2021-06-03}

\displaydate{2021-06-01}

\displaydate{2021-06}

\selectlanguage{french}

\displaydate{2021-06-03}

\displaydate{2021-06-01}

\displaydate{2021-06}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try to optimize my code with this method. By the way, may I ask the difference between `\nobreakspace` and `\c_space_tl`?

Comment: @Jinwen You don't want to break a line between day, month and year; `\nobreakspace` is equivalent to a tie `~` in the document (but here we can't use `~` because it would just mean a space).